# How do I place insets at exact positions on a ggplot and set the colors of geom_segment?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, insets, geom-segment

I'm creating an illustration of how loess works. My two queries are at the end of this question. First, setup:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(melanoma, package = "lattice")
mela <- as_tibble(melanoma)
tric = function(x) if_else(abs(x) < 1, (1 - abs(x)^3)^3, 0)
scl = function(x) (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))
mela1 <- mela %>%
  slice(1:9) %>%
  mutate(dist = abs(year - year[5]),
         scaled = scl(dist),
         weight = tric(scaled)
  )
mod1 <- lm(incidence ~ year, data = mela1, weights = weight) %>%
  augment(., mela1)
mela2 <- mela %>%
  slice(10:18) %>%
  mutate(dist = abs(year - year[5]),
         scaled = scl(dist),
         weight = tric(scaled)
  )
mod2 <- lm(incidence ~ year, data = mela2, weights = weight) %>%
  augment(., mela2)
mela3 <- mela %>%
  slice(19:27) %>%
  mutate(dist = abs(year - year[5]),
         scaled = scl(dist),
         weight = tric(scaled)
  )
mod3 <- lm(incidence ~ year, data = mela3, weights = weight) %>%
  augment(., mela3)
mela4 <- mela %>%
  slice(28:37) %>%
  mutate(dist = abs(year - year[5]),
         scaled = scl(dist),
         weight = tric(scaled)
  )
mod4 <- lm(incidence ~ year, data = mela4, weights = weight) %>%
  augment(., mela4)
```

The main plot:

```
col <- rainbow_hcl(start = 12, 4, l = 20)
colB <- rainbow_hcl(start = 12, 4, l = 100)
main <- ggplot(data = mela, aes(x = year, y = incidence)) +
# segment 1
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 1936, xend = 1944, y = 2.115717, yend = 2.115717)) +
# segment 2
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 1945, xend = 1953, y = 3.473217, yend = 3.473217)) +
# segment 3
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 1954, xend = 1962, y = 1.170247, yend = 1.170247)) +
# segment 4
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = 1963, xend = 1972, y = 2.7, yend = 2.7)) +
  geom_point(data = mod1, color = col[1], shape = 1) +
  geom_point(data = mod2, color = col[2], shape = 0) +
  geom_point(data = mod3, color = col[4], shape = 5) +
  geom_point(data = mod4, color = col[3], shape = 2) +
  geom_line(data = mod1, aes(x = year, y = .fitted), color = col[1]) +
  geom_line(data = mod2, aes(x = year, y = .fitted), color = col[2]) +
  geom_line(data = mod3, aes(x = year, y = .fitted), color = col[4]) +
  geom_line(data = mod4, aes(x = year, y = .fitted), color = col[3]) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1940, 1949, 1958, 1967))
```

Insets

```
inset1 <- ggplot(data = mod1, aes(x = year, y = weight)) +
  geom_line(color = col[1]) +
  geom_area(fill = colB[1]) +
  theme_void()
inset2 <- ggplot(data = mod2, aes(x = year, y = weight)) +
  geom_line(color = col[12) +
  geom_area(fill = colB[2]) +
  theme_void()
inset3 <- ggplot(data = mod3, aes(x = year, y = weight)) +
  geom_line(color = col[3]) +
  geom_area(fill = colB[3]) +
  theme_void()
inset4 <- ggplot(data = mod4, aes(x = year, y = weight)) +
  geom_line(color = col[4]) +
  geom_area(fill = colB[4]) +
  theme_void()
```

**Question 1:** How do I place the four insets so that the y = 0 of the weight function is at the height of the corresponding `geom_segment`? I would like the inset heights = 2 in the main figure coordinates.

***Question 2:*** How do I set the color of each segment to the color of the corresponding inset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether I got everything right. But I tried my best. (; You could simplify your code considerably

1. ... by binding you models data into one dataframe and also the data for the segments.
2. ... mapping on aesthetics and setting the colors and shape via some named vectors and `scale_xxx_manual`

For your insets there is no need to make separate plots and trying to put them into the main plot. You could simply add them via an additional `geom_line` and a `geom_ribbon`. To get the heights of the segments join the segments data to the models data so that you can set the starting value for the `geom_ribbon` according to the `y` value of the segment

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(colorspace)

col <- setNames(col, c("mod1", "mod2", "mod4", "mod3"))
colB <- setNames(colB, c("mod1", "mod2", "mod4", "mod3"))
shapes <- setNames(c(1, 0, 5, 2), c("mod1", "mod2", "mod3", "mod4"))

mods <- list(mod1 = mod1, mod2 = mod2, mod3 = mod3, mod4 = mod4) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "mod")

# segments data
dseg <- tribble(
  ~mod, ~x, ~xend, ~y,
  "mod1", 1936, 1944, 2.115717,
  "mod2", 1945, 1953, 3.473217,
  "mod3", 1954, 1962, 1.170247,
  "mod4", 1963, 1972, 2.7,
)

main <- ggplot(data = mela, aes(x = year, y = incidence)) +
  geom_segment(data = dseg, aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = y, color = mod)) +
  geom_point(data = mods, aes(color = mod, shape = mod)) +
  geom_line(data = mods, aes(x = year, y = .fitted, color = mod)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1940, 1949, 1958, 1967)) +
  guides(color = FALSE, shape = FALSE, fill = FALSE)

mods1 <- left_join(mods, select(dseg, mod, y), by = "mod")

# Add insets
main +
  geom_line(data = mods1, aes(x = year, y = weight + y, color = mod, group = mod)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = mods1, aes(x = year, ymin = y, ymax = weight + y, fill = mod, group = mod)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colB)
```

[image]